# Django allauth register button has suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have never had any problems with it previously but when I clicked on it just then, it did not do anything. However my login works fine.

I'm running a custom signup class (so I can include google recaptcha) - this has already been tried and tested to work:

```
class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

I believe I may have altered the source code in [django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py) however I can't figure out what I changed. So I tried copy pasting the whole `forms.py` on github to my `forms.py`, and that returned this error:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/vorsso/venvor/draft1/views.py" in boxes_view
  116.     return render(request, 'boxes.html', context)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  205.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  59.             return next(self.gen)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
  263.             updates.update(processor(self.request))

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/app/draft1/processors.py" in everywhere
  12.     allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in __init__
  364.         super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in __init__
  321.             getattr(self, 'field_order', None) or default_field_order)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/utils.py" in set_form_field_order
  252.         for f in fields_order)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/utils.py" in <genexpr>
  252.         for f in fields_order)

Exception Type: KeyError at /news/
Exception Value: 'email2'
```

so I believe I may have tampered something with `email2`.

Any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT**

Ok when I remove `captcha = ReCaptchaField()` from my custom form the register works. Any idea why?

**EDIT2**

So it seems it works on chrome but not firefox. Some problem with google recaptcha not working on firefox.